Can I uninstall ZFS if using ext4 for everything?
I have never used ZFS for anything (that I know of).
To my surprise, there are 4 packages installed by default on my new installation of Linux Mint 22 (Cinnamon).
Naturally my question is, if I can uninstall all ZFS-related packages if using ext4 for everything? Safely I mean, if it is not used by any means internally. And if I can, how exactly to proceed?

Why do you want to remove it? If it is actually running (consuming CPU and memory), then I understand. Otherwise, are you so short of disk space? If you want to reduce storage, there are probably hundreds of packages that could be removed, but maintenance may become a nightmare.

@PeterBill I made a systemd-analyze something and I saw it grabbing some boot time. Cheers

First, run this to find if you actually have some ZFS-related packages installed:
$ dpkg -l | grep -i zfs

Second, simulate the removal of libzfs4linux, this one includes not all, but some ZFS packages.
$ sudo apt-get --simulate purge libzfs4linux


In my case, I found 4 ZFS packages, and 3 of them would have been removed, one missing was libzpool5linux.
So, I ended up running:
$ sudo apt-get purge libzfs4linux libzpool5linux

There did not seem to be any changes needed afterward.
Good luck, and backup everything as always before such a change.

I also have Mint 22 with Cinnamon and ext4. I tried several commands:
ps -ef | grep zfs

showed no ZFS processes running
systemd-analyze blame | grep zfs

showed four services that ran briefly during boot-up:

2.123s zfs-load-module.service
18ms zfs-share.service
15ms zfs-volume-wait.service
6ms zfs-mount.service


All of these services exited normally, as shown by
systemctl status zfs-load-module.service

and ditto for the other services.
It seems to me (as a complete non-expert in boot internals) that they were simply looking for ZFS volumes to mount, then stopped when there were none.
If you REALLY want to save a couple of seconds of boot time (probably less in clock time if your system runs services in parallel), then simply disable these services.
sudo systemctl disable <service name>

Disabling a service is much less dangerous than uninstalling a package, although there is still a risk that you end up with a system that will not boot. I cannot quantify the risk, so you proceed at your own risk. MAKE SURE YOU BACK UP ALL YOUR DATA AND ANY CHANGED CONFIGURATION FILES. If you are worried, have a live boot USB handy, Mint is easy enough to re-install.
